# Celery Config in Airflow 2.7.0 or higher

Tags: airflow, celery, airflow-2.x

I need to replace the broker_url setting of celery.

In the previous Airflow versions I simply used the [celery] section in airflow.cfg.
But this section was moved since Airflow 2.7.0 to the packages configs, as stated [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-celery/stable/configurations-ref.html#celery):

> The configuration embedded in provider packages started to be used as of Airflow 2.7.0. Previously the configuration was described and configured in the Airflow core package...

The package [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) stats that:

> you must create the celeryconfig.py module and make sure it’s available on the Python path.

I did that.

The file celeryconfig.py:

```
broker_url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
```

But it is still refusing to change the broker URL. Therefore, my question is, how (step-by-step) can I set this setting now?

**Edit:**
I used the CELERY_BROKER_URL environment variable as a temporary solution. I would glad to find out a way to put it in a config file.

Comment: I think the documentation refers that before it was in the `[core]`, now it is in `[celery]`. However for this to work at all, in the [core] section you need to use CeleryExecutor.

Comment: I am using the CeleryExecutor. And unfortunately, there's no [celery] section on Airflow 2.7.0 cfg file.